# How can I slice an 3D object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a 3d game , and I want to slice an object ( I create 2 prefabs , one of the object normal and the other sliced) . Can anyone help me with a script ( Slice like FRUIT NINJA)

Comment: May work for you -> https://github.com/DavidArayan/ezy-slice

Comment: I recommend not using any slice of 3D meshes since it may reduce your games performance. Design the object (fruit) in a way its already shattered but keep the parts together. Once you want to slice, you can add any animation to the meshes. If you want any precise dynamic slicing, Ezy Slice is a good way to go.

Comment: I want to do it with touch ( app for mobile)